# How can I nest a singularity grid inside another

Tags: singularitygs

Is it possible to nest grids with Singularity?

Here is my setup:

```
$break: 500px;
$break1: 700px;
$break2: 900px;
$break3: 1200px;

$grids: 3;
$grids: add-grid(6 at $break);
$grids: add-grid(12 at $break1);
$grids: add-grid(2 8 2 at $break2);
$grids: add-grid(3 6 1 1 1 at $break3);

$gutters: 1/3;
$gutters: add-gutter(.25 at 900px);
$output: 'isolation';
```

The current context I'm asking about is inside `$break3`.

I would like to have the following grid structure.

*I realise the below isn't right it is just there as a demonstration as to the grid structure I'd like to have. I have tried using functions to output the correct widths but have had no luck, but that is probably because I was doing it all wrong.*

HTML structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="1">
        <div class="1-a"></div>
        <div class="1-b"></div>
        <div class="1-c"></div>
        <div class="1-d"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="2"></div>
</div>
```

SCSS

- div.1: `@include grid-span(4, 2);`
- div.1-a nested in div1 and span the first column of 4
- div.1-b nested in div1 and span the last 3 columns of 4
- div.1-c nested in div1 and span the last 3 columns of 4 stacked below 1-b
- div.1-d nested in div1 and span the last 3 columns of 4 stacked below 1-c
- div.2: `@include grid-span(1, 1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can! `$grids` only deals with your main grid context, but if you would like to change your grid context, you can either override your grid context [through grid-span](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Spanning-The-Grid#context-overrides) or you can do it through the [layout mixin](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Spanning-The-Grid#group-context-overrides).

Also take a look at this [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377578/still-confused-with-nested-grids) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16378912/703084).